# FATAL:flutter/lib/ui/window/platform_message_response_dart_port.cc(53) Check failed: did_send

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates

Receiving above error when uploading files in chunks to Azure and recording audio simultaneously. This issue occurs only when there is a switch in network of the device. We are using dio to upload the chunks to Azure.

We created an isolate to lower the memory consumption by the app but still we are facing the same issue. Then issue occurs after Isolate.kill is called to kill the isolate in case of error due to the network.